# Join 2 data frame based on range values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have 2 data frames with column start and end with no repetitions, sorted by each range. For example:

df1:

```
start end
10    20
21    35
37    50
```

df2:

```
start end
12    15
17    19
22    24
26    29
31    40
43    46
```

I want to get a new data frame based on a join operation of `df2` range that is within range of `df1` as follows:

```
range.df1 range.df2    
10:20     12:15
10:20     17:19
21:35     22:24
21:35     26:29
21:35     31:35
37:50     37:40
37:50     43:46
```

Can someone tell me how can I achieve this in R?

Comment: You want final output as string columns ? `10:20` `12:15` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `foverlaps`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = names(df1))
setDT(df2, key = names(df2))
foverlaps(df1, df2)[, .(range.df1 = paste(i.start, i.end, sep=":"), 
          range.df2 = paste(start, end, sep=":"))]
#    range.df1 range.df2
#1:     10:20     12:15
#2:     10:20     17:19
#3:     21:35     22:24
#4:     21:35     26:29
#5:     21:35     31:40
#6:     37:50     31:40
#7:     37:50     43:46
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(start = c(10L, 21L, 37L), end = c(20L, 35L, 50L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(start = c(12L, 17L, 22L, 26L, 31L, 43L), end = c(15L, 
19L, 24L, 29L, 40L, 46L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```